# If one purchases a machine and software that has no EULA, etc, can said person legally alter the code of the program purchased?

Tags: united-states, copyright, licensing, eula

So say myself or a company sells a printer, and as part of that printer package you have an add-on to purchase software with it. The customer purchases the machine and software and accepts terms you have laid out on the site, but that doesn't outline use, rights, or licensing of the software purchased as an add-on with the machine.

There is no EULA to accept when running or using the software, and no terms outlined on the website, within the software, or anywhere for the purchaser or end user. So no agreement, no EULA, no restrictions or anything outline for use of the program purchased.

Do they own the software? Can they legally alter the code of the program they purchased? Can they legally redistribute it or transfer ownership? Can they legally modify the code of the program for others who have also purchased the same package? Can they take that software and install it on a secondary machine?

Comment: "Can they legally modify the code of the program..." - does the distribution include source code? And if so, does the source code state a license of some sort in it (e.g. an open source license)? Without source code, it's normally extremely difficult to modify software, though technically it's possible.

Comment: It has all of my source code, and no it doesn't state any license.

Comment: See also: [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license). In your case, you didn't publish it publicly, but the basic rule still applies. No license = no permission to copy/redistribute.

Comment: Though from a practical point of view, I'd consider placing at least some kind of simple license or simple statement in your source code in the future. As a programmer, if I find source code on my machine, then at some point it's simply going to be too tempting to try to make changes and compile a private version for myself (technically that's making a copy or a derivative work, so strictly not allowed without permission).

Comment: My only concern is they bought the software with the printer, so technically I sold it to them. The link you posted is someone finding code online and wanting to use it.

Comment: I don't see why that would matter. If I sell you a photo book, I don't automatically sell you the right to make copies of those photos and redistribute those copies. Maybe I can't even sell that because I'm not necessarily the one who owns the copyright on the photos, anyway. In your case, it just so happens that you wrote the software, but you could always claim that your software includes elements from third parties which don't permit further redistributions of their code.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the basic principle of copyright law, as detailed in [17 USC 106](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106):

The copyright holder has the **exclusive** right to make copies; prepare derivative works; or distribute copies by sale, rental, lease, or lending.  Other people can legally do these things **only** if they are given permission by the copyright holder, typically via a *license*.  (Remember, the literal meaning of the word *license* is *permission*.)  Often, the copyright holder will require a prospective licensee to accept various terms and conditions before the license will be granted.

If there is "no EULA", or if there is one but the purchaser has not agreed to its terms, then the purchaser has not been granted any such license, hence does not have permission to do any of the things listed above.  If they do so anyway, it is illegal copyright infringement and they will be liable for damages.

To use a firewall analogy, copyright law is "default deny".

So let's take your questions one by one:

- Do they own the software?

US law has no concept of literally *owning* software.  The closest thing is *owning the copyright*, which the purchaser certainly does not.  It still belongs to the vendor that wrote the software (or whoever they may have later transferred it to).

- Can they legally alter the code of the program they purchased?

No, that would be preparing a derivative work.  The copyright holder has not granted them a license to do that.  (There are some exceptions for purposes such as reverse engineering and interoperability, see [17 USC 1201(f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/1201)).

- Can they legally redistribute it

No; again, that is the exclusive right of the copyright holder, and the purchaser has not received their permission.

- or transfer ownership?

Maybe, if the [first sale doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-sale_doctrine) applies.  Its application to software is complicated.  The user has a better case for being able to sell the software if it exists as some tangible object which is transferred (physical media, pre-installed on hardware, etc).

- Can they legally modify the code of the program for others who have also purchased the same package?

No, that would be preparing a derivative work.

- Can they take that software and install it on a secondary machine?

No, that would be making a copy.

Comment: They are saying because I sold them the software with the machine and didn't include any terms or licensing agreement, they are able to modify or redistribute it.

Comment: Also, what is the reverse engineering? They mentioned that as well.

Comment: "They are saying because I sold them the software with the machine and didn't include any terms or licensing agreement, they are able to modify or redistribute it."  They are wrong, to the best of my knowledge.  Again, 'default deny'.  If you had included a licensing agreement, they would have whatever rights the agreement granted them.  If you did not include any, then they have *no rights at all*, other than rights such as fair use that everyone always has.

Comment: There is a terms and conditions they accept before purchase, but that doesn't have any licensing in it.

Comment: @NahLedge: Do note that this site does not give legal advice on specific situations.  I am describing how copyright law works in general, according to my understanding.  If you want to know how it applies in your particular case then you hire a lawyer and consult them.

Comment: I'm fully aware. I'm here asking questions to know more before I take any action.

Comment: @NahLedge "They are saying because I ... didn't include any terms ... they are able to modify or redistribute it." - This is a bit like saying that because I didn't place a "no trespassing" sign on my closed-off property, that therefore everyone is allowed to open the gate and go inside without my permission.

Comment: I understand that, but my worry is I sold them the software. Your trespassing is someone who should on the property at all, whereas my concern is the fact they purchased it.

Comment: The principle is that if you have nothing that says otherwise, you only have the rights given to you by copyright law, which isn't very much. If you have no EULA and nothing else then plain copyright law applies. It is very unlikely that you sold someone software. Ok, there is some software that I wrote personally, that is distributed on Apple's App Store, that I would be willing to sell to you for £10,000. Complete with all the copyrights.

Comment: If someone claims you sold them some software when you didn't, and then they commit copyright infringement, that is their problem (unless you mislead them and claimed they would have rights that they don't).

Comment: So more context:
I sold a printer I manufactured and software (that I developed on top of an open source project) that runs the printer to a customer, who reached out and said their mainboard (its a motherboard in the printer with windows 10 installed and has my software and source code copied onto it) has gone bad. They are not under warranty and refused to pay for a new board from me. They then copied all of my source code and software onto another computer and are running their printer and my software off of that, to bypass buying a board from me.

Comment: Do I have any legal recourse? Is it legal for them to copy my software and source files onto another computer to run their printer?
They are also talking about making third party accessories for my printers, and altering code to enable to use of third party accessories.I did not provide any licensing or EULA with the printer or software.

Comment: *that I developed on top of an open source project*: So it sounds like you created and distributed a derivative work of the open source code.  Did *its* license permit you to do that?  Many open source licenses would oblige to provide a similar license to all your customers, so if you didn't do that, then *you* may be infringing the copyright of the open source project.  The customer may still be infringing yours, but now there is a risk that if you threaten to sue them, they may convince the open-source project's copyright holders to sue you.

Comment: @NahLedge: I think you really need to consult with a copyright lawyer if you intend to pursue this in any way.  The details are past the point of what can be answered with general information about the law.